# How do I manage subscription using Stripe.js

Tags: stripe-payments

How do I manage subscription using Stripe.js.

Basically, I need to create a subscription, change a subscription, delete a subscription and check if a subscription is active.

The demos and examples on the Stripe site only use PHP, Node.js, Ruby etc. They do not show how to do it using javascript and Strip.js.

Answer (score 1):

[Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js) can only be used to create a card or a bank account token in the browser. Once this is done you need to send it to your server where you would create a [charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) or a [subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_subscription).

The same would go to [update](https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_subscription) or [cancel](https://stripe.com/docs/api#cancel_subscription) and existing subscription and this can only happen on the server. You would offer a button in your UI for example so that your customer can cancel his subscription but you would just post to your server where you effectively cancel it.

You could also look at the list of third-party services that integrate Stripe and offer [recurring payments](https://stripe.com/docs/integrations#recurring-payments) such as [Charge Rabbit](https://chargerabbit.com/) or [Recurly](https://recurly.com/).